# Wordpress shortcode - weird position on page

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I created shortcode in my child themes `functions.php` file. 
The `shortcode` is as follows:

```
function add_login_form() {
if ( is_user_logged_in() )
{
    echo 'Witaj zalogowany';
}
else 
{
    wp_login_form();
}
}
add_shortcode('login_form', 'add_login_form');
```

I added shortcode `[login_form]` to my website (test area):
http://s540141209.domenaklienta.pl/wordpress/konto-klienta/

It is added to website after the text:
"TUTAJ POWINIEN BYĆ LOGIN FORM LUB NAPIS „WITAJ ZALOGOWANY”!"

It should be inside first div: `<div class="et_pb_row">`

But it is shown just after the header of a page. Have you any idea why it happens that way?

Thansk in advance. 
But it happens to show before everything on website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API on how shortcodes acts. In a shortcode function you should always return the result of the processing done in the shortcode action. Echoing it outputs it as soon as the hook is executed, instead of being inserted in where it should be.

```
function add_login_form() {
if ( is_user_logged_in() )
{
    return 'Witaj zalogowany';
}
else 
{
    return wp_login_form(array('echo'=>false));
}
}
add_shortcode('login_form', 'add_login_form');
```

For all arguments of wp_login_form, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form .

Comment: I read the Shortcode_API article from codex and also some tutorial article on the internet but it was unclear for me how this 'return' works instead of echo.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what is 'hook' and when it is executed, but I can live with it as long as my code will work. And now it does. 

Great thanks Friso.